# Can we say "I will come back and take the bag after putting you in the stroller"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

You, Your little child and a big toy bag are in a house. Your stroller is outside the house by the door.

Now you want to leave, because you can't carry both the child and the big toy bag to the stroller at once so you want to put the child in the stroller first and get the bag later.

Is it natural say to the child this "**I will come back and take the bag after putting you in the stroller**"?

**Note**: The parent, the child & the bag all go home or to the same place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like "take" there; I would use "bring", unless the parent and the child are going to different places (i.e., the child is being taken somewhere else by someone else).

You could simply say

> I will bring the bag after ... or I will get the back after I put you ...

Comment: The parent, the child & the bag all go home or to the same place.